# Is there a way to run a separate Update at a faster rate than the Application.targetFrameRate?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am looking to poll Unity inputs over the last several frames and use that data to interpret the user's button presses. From what I've tested however, it feels like polling at the application's 60 FPS framerate leads to some very fast inputs getting missed.

Simple example, user tries to go to Forward from Down:

```
frame 1 - user is holding Down
frame 1.5 - user taps Forward, but hasn't released Down yet
frame 2 - user lets go of Down and has reached Forward fully
```

In my current set up, using unity's framerate update, frame 1.5 where the user has both Down and Forward held is missed entirely. Is there a way to run a separate update, that runs at a faster rate than the regular Unity MonoBehaviour Update function? Or would a different solution be needed, such as querying via events(iirc that's an option, but I may be misremembering)?

Comment: Could you share your code? And no you can't (not with the built-in input system). But: In reality there is no such thing as a 1.5 frame ... if the user pressed and released a button since the last frame then in the next Update call both `Input.GetButtonDown` and `Input.GetButtonUp` will return `true`! So I'd claim the issue is in how you implemented the Input .. Or my question would be: Why do you think that an Input matters if there is no frame going to be rendered for it so what effect/impact should it have?

Comment: I don't think sharing the code would help in this case. my point w/ the 1.5 frame is that input can be read at a 1 milisecond frequency on some devices, which is much more granular than a single frame. I see what you mean when you say the Input system wouldn't account for that tho.

Comment: As I said .. the Input system **does** account for it and tells you that the key was pressed and already released since the last frame .. so you can definitely deduct from that that at se point during the last frame the two key where pressed at the same time ... my question is: Why would you care? What exactly does that change in your Gameplay?

Comment: it changes the responsiveness of the game and potentially gives a bad game feel if you're interpreting inputs over several frames, like with a quarter circle forward motion in Street Fighter for example

Comment: I don't know what a quarter circle forward motion in Street Fighter looks like tbh ^^ But no I still don't really get the point

Comment: humans don't run at 60fps, so their input is faster and unreliable. by making the polling at a finer scale, we can avoid input overlap on the same frame and potentially make the game feel less clunky. it's p hard to rationalise if you haven't played an input intensive game, but having that extra granularity can make a lot of difference to the general feel

Comment: I still don't really see what difference it makes whether you can track the input or not in a higher frame-rate if in the end the rendered output and how that input is applied is frame based anyway. As said Unity does track the input higher grained internally .. you don't miss Inputs between the frames ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to decouple polling frequency from frame rate in legacy input system, however in new input system there is a pollingFrequency property that allows you define the frequency in Hertz. It uses a background thread to poll the data. You also need to subscribe to an input action change and record your values there to finally consume them in update method.

Comment: What is this "new input system"? If I were to consume the inputs in the update method, wouldn't that circle back to the original issue of polling at the application's frame rate? or are you referring to a separate background thread update and not the generic MonoBehaviour one?

Comment: here it is: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html

Comment: And you are right, that's why you need to subscribe to some event, a background thread with a higher frequency will invoke this events

Comment: thank you, I'll see if I can make use of this in my current implementation

Comment: Honestly I still don't really get what your expected gain by this would be though